# Would moving to Denmark jeopardize US work visas in the future?

Tags: usa, eu, indian-citizens

I am currently working in India and hold Indian citizenship.

I have an opportunity to spend 2-3 years in Denmark and then move to US on a L1B visa which will hopefully lead to a H1B followed by a green card (hopefully before I die).

If I continue in India, the US opportunity is unaffected and I will still get it sometime in 2017.

Spending a few years in Denmark is something I would certainly like to do, however moving to the US is a longer-term goal of mine.

Would moving to US from Denmark (which is not my home country) significantly complicate matters?

Comment: It's unclear whether your time in Denmark would be associated with your US opportunity. Is this all working for the same multinational company, for example? Or would the time you spend in Denmark be unrelated to the US opportunity?

Comment: @GregHewgill Same company. I am currently wrapping up a project, and will be starting a new one that will last till 2017 when I will be eligible for one in US. I can pick a project in India or one in Denmark

Comment: You might be required to go to India for visa processing, depending on your Denmark status, but other than that - no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For US immigration on a temporary work permit, they won't care much where you are moving *from* (whether Denmark or India). They probably won't even ask.

For permanent immigration (US green card), countries typically want to see a police report or equivalent from other countries where you have lived more than a certain amount of time (I don't know specifically what the US requires in this area). So eventually, if you decide to work for a time in Denmark, the US might require a report from the Danish police. This is a common request, especially for migrants, and should be easy to get.